# Postgresql -> Difference between value from now and last month

Tags: sql, postgresql

I wanted to make a query where i have the following result:

```
Value - Date Reference - Previus Value - Previus Date
20    - 01-07-2020     -     15        -   01-06-2020
50    - 01-10-2021     -     40        -   01-09-2021
```

I tried a first_value function, but it only retourned the first value, not the previus one.

Also those values would be grouped by an client ID. So that I can identify where i had contraction or expansion on my resoults.

Comment: I removed mysql tag, since you mentioned postgresql in your question, please only tag the database you are using

Answer (score 0):

you can use `LAG` function :

```
select * 
  , lag(Value) over (order by DateReference) previousValue
  , lag(DateReference) over (order by DateReference) previousdate
from tablename
```